# React styled-component / e2e testing: What is the best way to use css selector?

Tags: reactjs, nightwatch.js, styled-components

I use [styled-components](https://www.styled-components.com/) in a react app and I got a problem with e2e testing.

Since styled-components generates hashed classes, it's hard to use [nightwatch](http://nightwatchjs.org/api) css selectors.

Is it possible to add prefix to generated classes so I could use .attributeContains() assertion?

Or is there a better solution ?

Comment: if you're using `styled-components` then it may be better in general to select with another attribute rather than `class`.

Answer (score 1):

Styled-components has prefixed classes with "sc-" and you can add your own classNames to the styled-component with `.attrs()` or add a custom className to any instance of it with `className`.

```
const Component = styled.div.attrs({
  className: 'PrefixedComponentClass',
})`
  color: pink;
`;
```

or

```
<Component className={'PrefixedComponentInstanceClass'} />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the library: [jest-styled-components](https://github.com/styled-components/jest-styled-components)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).